# Android Virtual Device Component

Tags: android-studio, installation, genymotion

Do I have to tick 'Android Virtual Device' component in the installer if I am going to use Genymotion as emulator?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Genymotion comes with its own virtual devices so you don't need those from Android Studio.